# ProgressDialog NullPointerException when calling AsyncTask Class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, progressdialog

I am experiencing a `NullPointerException` when I am trying to call the `execute` method of a `AsyncTask` class.

This is my code:

```
public class NewCustomersRetrieve extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewCustomers.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Getting list");
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
}
```

In my RecyclerView class this is where I call the NewCustomersRetrieve

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.btnDownloadFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NewCustomers newCustomers = new NewCustomers();
                NewCustomers.NewCustomersRetrieve NewCustomersRetrieve = newCustomers.new NewCustomersRetrieve();
                newCustomersRetrieve.execute();
            }
        });
```

I suspect it is something to do with the `onBindViewHolder()` method in my other class. I guess someone here can explain where I have gone wrong

This is the `print stack`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:146)
            at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:103)
            at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:143)
            at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
            at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
            at lukasz.musik.NewCustomers$NewCustomersRetrieve.onPreExecute(NewCustomers.java:254)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
            at lukasz.musik.CustomMusicAdapter$1.onClick(CustomMusicAdapter.java:67)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post your stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Sure, please check OP

Comment: Is NewCustomers an Activity?

Comment: Yes, it is an Activity

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen on the button click?  Do you want to launch the NewCustomers Activity?  Or just run the AsyncTask?  Also, does your RecyclerView Adapter live inside an Activity (inner class of Activity), or is it a separate class?

Comment: Regardless, your problem almost certainly lies in the fact that you are calling `new NewCustomers()`.  Never call `new` on an Activity in Android, always use `startActivity()`.  In your case the Activity has not been started, so the Context is null.

Answer (score 2):

Well you're on the right track, as you can see this is the offending line:

```
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewCustomers.this);
```

The ProgressDialog is expecting a Context as it's parameter.

You initialise a new `NewCustomers` and then create the new `NewCustomersRetrieve` on it, but it looks like it will be missing a reference to your apps Context?

---

Based on the comments by you and Daniel Nugent, you may want to look at 
[Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

You should use something the lines of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CustomMusicAdapter.this, NewCustomers.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And then inside the NewCustomers Activity handle your NewCustomersRetrieve logic.

Comment: So what should I do? What is the fix/cure?

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci Updated my answer to include potential solution.

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci Still the exact same error? what if you change the `CustomMusicAdapter.this` with `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: Its not letting me because it is in an `onClick()` method which has `View v`. Even if I try `v.getApplicationContext` it is not allowing me

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put your asynctask into your adapter class or pass the context in adapter into it constructor!

Answer (score 0):

On Post execute, dismiss the progress dialog as shown below

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer results) {
        super.onPostExecute(results);

        if(pd != null && pd.isShowing()){
            pd.dismiss();
            pd=null;
        }

}
```